# How is the Yahoo mailbox accessed from these programs?

Tags: email

There are a lot of programs out there that can access yahoo's mailbox and notify you for new mail. How do these programs work? Yahoo doesn't provide POP or IMAP access.

Comment: Did my answer offer you some help?

Comment: Do you have any ideas for hotmail?

Comment: Also, the service you suggested requires that the web page be redirected to a yahoo page first to log in and then redirect back. This won't work for a software.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine these programs are taking advantage of the [Yahoo! Mail Web Service](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/)

Answer (score 0):

There are examples given in a number of different programming languages on the [Yahoo! Mail Web Service](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/) website that Jamie's talking about:

[C#](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/code/mail_cs.zip)

[Perl](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/J/JL/JLEV/Yahoo-BBAuth-0.50.tar.gz)

[PHP](http://developer.yahoo.com/auth/quickstart/bbauth_quickstart.zip)

[Python](http://developer.yahoo.com/python/samples/ybrowserauth.zip)

[Java JAX-WS](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/code/mail_java_JAX.zip)

[Java Axis2](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/code/mail_java.zip)

These code examples show how it's possible to access Yahoo mail using code, without requiring the redirect you mention.